# Python: Twisted server and values

Tags: python, process, twisted

I'd like access to the same value in my protocol and in my factory so I made a test with this code:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

class MyServer(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append("client")
        print self.factory.clients


class MyServerFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def __init__(self):
    self.protocol = MyServer
        self.clients = []

    def printClient(self):
        print self.clients

if __name__ == '__main__':
    factory = MyServerFactory()
    reactor.listenTCP(4433, factory)
    processTwisted = Process(target=reactor.run)
    processTwisted.start()
    time.sleep(10)
    factory.printClient()
```

During the sleep I connect client to the server.
This is the console's log :

```
['client']
[]
```

And I expected:

```
['client']
['client']
```

How can do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Twisted and `multiprocessing` don't work together like this.  Also, lists and `multiprocessing` don't work together like this.

If you remove the use of `multiprocessing` you'll get the behavior you want.